# Crontab to run R Script on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have an R script which is running on an Amazon EC2 instance. I want to write a cronjob so that the script is executed automatically every 10 minutes. When I try to make the script executable with

```
chmod +x Script.R
```

I get an error message telling me:
"chmod: changing permissions of 'Script.R': Operation not permitted".

The same happens if I try to execute it indirectly via:

```
chmod +x execute.sh
```

I did put

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

in the first line of my Rscript and I do have a SSH-connection established and I have a bash command line.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What O/S user owns the script and what O/S user are you?

Comment: I tried 

    cat /etc/passwd

But it shows me a long list only. I used the predefined community template of Rstudio which can be find here: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/.

Comment: You might want to read up on some Unix basics but you can see who the file is owned by doing `ls -l Script.R`.  It will look something like `-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 1194 Dec  7  2016 Script.R` where `user` is who owns the file.  You can see who you are with the `id` command - it gives something like: `uid=1001(user) gid=1001(group) groups=1001(group)`.  Assuming pretty normal permissions if the user that owns the file is not the same as you're logged in as then you won't have permission to `chmod` the file.  Again, I'd read up on some Unix/Linux basics to assist.